# Error handling best practices - async pipe

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

is there some kind of best practise in async pipe error handling? Is it preferable to handle errors in service(but that means we have to use some kind of global error handling) or it is better in component? What do you guys prefer?

For example in my service i have getter which is then consumed in component:

```
//service
get loadedEvents(){
 //appStatus emits when selectedMonth is changed
    return this.statusService.appStatus.pipe(                                             
    switchMap(status=>this.getOffers(status.selectedMonth)),         
    shareReplay({refCount:true})); }

getOffers(date:Date){
    return this.httpClient.get(...);
}

//component
events$=this.service.loadedEvents;
```

Where is it better to catch error? In component or service?

Comment: That highly depends on whether different components will consume the same observable, whether errors should be handled differently in different components and whether you want to display something to the user globally or in the specific component.

Comment: Ideally the error handling would be handled in the service, IMHO, resulting in the compontent only receiving the expected data. How you process those errors then (ie. log them to a db, display some msg to the user) is up to personal preference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, don't use a getter. This creates a new memory reference everytime [(see this)](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-ym99py?devtoolsheight=60&file=index.ts)

Instead, use pipeable operators.

```js
loadedEvents = this.statusService
  .appStatus
  .pipe(                                             
    switchMap(status=>this.getOffers(status.selectedMonth)),         
    shareReplay({refCount:true})
  );
```

Next, for the errors : you can create a structural directive, made to handle the errors when they appear. Something like this : [(See it in action)](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-2xbz7z?file=src%2Fapp%2Fasyncerr.directive.ts%3AL7)

```js
export class AsyncerrDirective {
  @Input() asyncerr: Observable<any>;
  @Input() asyncerrCatch: any;

  constructor(
    private viewRef: ViewContainerRef,
    private tplRef: TemplateRef<any>
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.asyncerrCatch);

    this.viewRef.clear();

    this.asyncerr.pipe(tap(() => this.viewRef.clear())).subscribe({
      next: (asyncerr) => {
        const ref = this.viewRef.createEmbeddedView(this.tplRef);
        ref.context = { asyncerr, $implicit: asyncerr };
      },
      error: (error) => {
        const ref = this.viewRef.createEmbeddedView(this.tplRef);
        ref.context = { [this.asyncerrCatch]: error };
      },
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<ng-container *asyncerr="data$ as data; catch: 'error'; let error = error">
  <ng-container *ngIf="error; else dataTpl">
    {{ error }}
  </ng-container>

  <ng-template #dataTpl>
    {{ data | json }}
  </ng-template>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Nice solution , only problem is, that if error occurs, it breaks the observable stream so it wont load any new data when appStatus changes... How to solve this problem?

Comment: @vartex05 depending on your need, use the retry operator, or map to a specific value like `{ error: '...' }` so that the stream does not break

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your need:

**Case 1** - Cath all the errors and show with toaster messages

Yes, in this case, we can catch the error in services and push the error to the toaster message service & component

**Case 2** - Showing message inside the component

We need to catch the error in every component